# How to detect diagonal swipe gesture in as3 for android

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I detect a diagonal swipe gesture which will enable a character jump over the obstacle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting diagonal swipe gesture for android in as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034235/detecting-diagonal-swipe-gesture-for-android-in-as3)

Comment: I hadn't asked the question properly so I decided to rewrite and post the question again.

Comment: Also, I urgently need to understand how this diagonal swipe gesture works so if you can help, it'll be really nice!

Comment: Don't delete and repost the same question.  Instead, edit your question with new details if they are needed.

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't realize that there is an edit option.

Answer (score 0):

according [This](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/) tutorial

> The function will be able to retrieve the variables offsetX and
>   offsetY to detect the direction in which the swipe was made from this
>   way:
>
> 1. if the value of offsetX is positive 1 then the swipe was made from the left to the right, if -1 then the swipe was made from the right to
>      the left.
> 2. if the value of offsetY is positive 1 then the swipe was made from the top to the bottom, if -1 then the swipe was made from the bottom
>      to the top.

so, for a diagonal swipe, **offsetX** should be same as **offsetY**

---

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe);
function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
    if (e.offsetX == e.offsetY) {
        // diagonal swipe
    }
}
```